# JOGL screenshot without overlaid dialogs interfering

Tags: java, windows-xp, overlay, screenshot, jogl

Hey I ran into an issue with taking a Screenshot from JOGL on windows XP (works fine in Win 7) where if I try to take a snapshot off my GLCanvas and there is a dialog on it, it will also include that dialog in the screenshot.

I used the ScreenShot class in JOGL.
I have also tried Pbuffers and manually glreadpixelling from GL.GLBACK but still same outcome.
Anyone else have  an idea of how to make JOGL ignore these non-gl dialogs?

Answer (score 0):

You should use java.awt.Robot class. It works fine for me.